# How to controled yii2 checkbox check?

Tags: php, checkbox, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have a checkbox and I want to control it's check situation. if it checked it'll show other code blocks. 
This my checkbox:

```
$form->field( $model, 'password')->checkbox()->label('Change Password');
```

And

```
$form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput()->textInput(['value'=>' '])->label('New Password');
```

Comment: I believe there must be something after "And" ?

Comment: Sorry I missed.After and : $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput()->textInput(['value'=>' '])->label('New Password');

Comment: use JQuery to show/hide password input depending of checkbox value, and also add to model validation rules to validate password input only when checkbox is checked

Comment: Yes, basically, only with the help of JavaScript/jQuery you can display or hide the field.